# WARNINGS module not found: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11 - Intellij/Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, maven-scala-plugin

So I installed Intellij along with the Scala plugin.  When I try to create my first scala project in the IDE, the dialog box comes up where you specify the name and location of the project, as well as the locations of the necessary SDK's.  I referenced Java's SDK easily, but nowhere can I find the Scala JDK - A search of my computer comes up empty. No matter - the dialog box in which I am to create a Scala SDK has an option to dowload it right there - but then it comes up with the following error when I try.

```
Getting org.fusesource.jansi jansi 1.11 ...
:: problems summary :: :::: WARNINGS
module not found: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::: ERRORS
:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS unresolved dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries   (see C:\Users\Augustine\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log) Error: Could not retrieve jansi 1.11 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0
```

Simply put, what can I do to avoid this error and get Scala working in IntelliJ? Thanks!

Comment: In my case it was proxy setting. Corrected the settings and then all worked.

Answer (score 2):

you might be getting problem of downloading dependencies runtime because of poor internet connection
you  can manually download all dependencies xml and jar files.. and you can get all those files here
http://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt

or instead of intellij IDE, go for **scala IDE for eclipse**... in eclipse we dont need to set sbt externally.